# Paypal production issue with paypal-rest-api-sdk

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been integrating PayPal with my application and I had no issues with the sandbox mode and after testing and everything was done I pushed it onto the production server and I ran into the following issue:

> PayPalConfigurationException
>   Getter function for 'payer' in 'PayPal\Api\Payment' class should have a proper return type.

I am not an expert in dev-ops and it seems the problem is server related rather than code related so any help or tips would be appreciated

I have googled the problem and found the following [issue on the Github repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/309)

This is also included in the [docs](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/class-should-have-a-proper-return-type)

I went ahead and modified the servers `php.ini` file and enabled comments and put the `[opcache]` following fields to 1:

```
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.load_comments=1
```

If you need any additional info feel free to ask me and I hope someone will be able to help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you restarted your server for the changes to take effect?

Comment: So i need to restart it in order for it to take effect? I am guessing there is no way around it right?

Comment: You can restart just the webserver, it'll take literally 2 seconds downtime